# Running an experiment with different parameters, saving outputs efficiently

Tags: python, cluster-computing, slurm, experimental-design

My task is:

- I have a program, written in Python which takes a set of variables (A,B,C) as input, and outputs two numbers (X, Y).
- I want to run this program over a large range of inputs (A,B,C)

  - I'll refer to running the program with a given set of variables as 'running an experiment'
- I am using a cluster to do this (I submit my jobs in SLURM)
- I then want to save the results of the experiments into a single file, e.g. a data frame with columns [A|B|C|X|Y], where each row is the output of a different experiment.

My current situation is:

- I have written my program in the following form:

  ```
  import io
  from optparse import OptionParser

  parser = OptionParser()

   parser.add_option("-f", "--file",action="store", type="string", dest="filename")
   parser.add_option("-a", "--input_a",type="int", dest="a")
   parser.add_option("-b", "--input_b",type="int", dest="b")
   parser.add_option("-c", "--input_c",type="int", dest="c")
  (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

   def F(a,b,c):
       return((a+b, b+c))

   Alice = options.input_a
   Bob = options.input_b
   Carol = options.input_c

    with io.open("results_a_{0}_b_{1}_c_{2}.txt".format(Alice, Bob, Carol), "a") as f:
       (x,y) = F(Alice, Bob, Carol)
       f.write(u"first output = {0}, second output = {1}".format(x,y))
  ```
- This allows me to run the program once, and save the results in a single file.
- In principle, I could then submit this job for a range of (A,B,C), obtain a large number of text files with the results, and then try to aggregate them into a single file.
- However, I assume this isn't the best way of going about things.

What I'd like to know is:

- Is there a more natural way for me to run these experiments and save the results all in one file, and if so, what is it?
- How should I submit my collection of jobs on SLURM to do so?

  - I currently am submitting (effectively) the script below, which is not really working:

...

```
      for a in 1 2 3; do
      for b in 10 20 30; do
      for c in 100 200 300; do
      python toy_experiment.py -a $a -b $b -c $c &
      done
      done
      done
      wait
```

[I'm wary that there are possibly many other places I'm going wrong here - I'm open to using something other than optparse to pass arguments to my program, to saving the results differently, etc. - my main goal is having a working solution.]

Comment: When saving output from multiple processes in one file you have to take care of one thing: _concurrency_. Consider using at least filesystem locks to synchronize file writes.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

You should research how to use file locking in your system and use that to access a single output file safely.

You should also submit your script usign a job array, and letting each job in the array to run a single experiment.

---

Many things going on here.

One important question: how long usually takes F() to compute? I assume that you just wrote an example, but this is required to decide the best approach to the problem.

If the time span for every calculation is short, maybe you can run few batches aggregating in a single script several computations: in the example, 3 batches (for a==1, a==2 and a==3), each of them gcomputing all the possible experiments for b and c and generating 3 files that have to be aggregated at the end.

If the timespan is long, then the overload of creating some thousands of small files is not a big deal. And concatenating them afterwards will be easy.

Another thing: by putting all your jobs running simultaneously in the backgroud you are probably overloading a single machine. I don't know how do you ask SLURM for resources, but for sure you will be using only one node. And overusing it. If there are other users there, they will probably be pissed off. You must control the number of simultaneous jobs running in a node to be the number of processors granted in that node. Propably, starting your calculations with srun will help.

Another way would be to create a single job per calculation. You can encapsulate them in a job array. In that case, you will only run one experiment per job and you won't have to start and wait for anything in the background.

Finally, getting to your main question: which is the best way to save all this information in disk efficiently.

Creating thousands of files is easy and possible, but not the best way for the file system. Maybe you have access to some RAMdisk in a common node. Writing a small file in compute node local storage and copying that file to the common in-memory disk would be quite a lot more efficient. And when all the experiments have been done you can aggregate the results easily. The drawback is that the space is usually very limited (I don't really know the real size of your data) and it will be an in-memory disk: it can be lost in case of power failure.

Using a single file would be a better approach, but as Dmitri Chubarov pointed, you have to make use of the file locking mechanisms. Otherwise you risk getting mixed results.

Finally, the approach that I feel is best suited for your problem, is to use some kind of database-like solution. If you have access to a relational DB that supports transactions, just create a table with the needed fields and let your code connect and insert the results. Extracting them at the end will be a breeze. The DB can be a client/server one (MySQL, PostgreSQL,Oracle...) or an embedded one (HSQLDB). Another option would be to use some file format like NetCDF, which is precisely intended for this kind of scientific data and have some support for parallel access.